# hello world in wxPython gets no reaction at all, no frame, no return

Tags: wxpython

First foray into python GUI and I'm using thenewboston tutorial.  First lesson with a basic frame, I get an error that wx.PySimpleApp() is depreciated and I follow the instructions here to change it to wx.App(False).  No errors come up, but also no frame. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx

class duckie(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id, 'Frame aka window', size = (300, 200))

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App(False)
    frame=duckie(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop
```

Originally I had everything spaced out (space after commas, before and after operators, etc) but I changed it to more accurately follow the tutorial with no difference in effect.  Understandably, I'm a little upset that I can't even get the Hello World to work here.

In case it's needed, the system is Ubuntu, everything is up to date through pip.

---

Solved.
For anyone else with this problem, I changed the id tag on line 10 from

```
frame=duckie(parent=None, id=-1)
```

to

```
frame=duckie(None, wx.ID_ANY)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.MainLoop
```

should be:

```
app.MainLoop()
```

'-1' or wx.ID_ANY is the same, do the following on a Python prompt:

```
import wx
wx.ID_ANY
```

The little sample I would probably do like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx


class Duckie(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Duckie, self).__init__(parent, id=wx.ID_ANY,
                                     title='Frame aka window',
                                     size=(300, 200))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Duckie(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The above code will pass PEP 8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) checking and will also have no errors when one uses e.g. PyLint to check ones code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Typo in the last line? It has to be

```
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It is typed precisely as the tutorial shows... and in the video it works out... is this another thing like the wx.PySimpleApp?  Any suggestions on what it perhaps should be?  Also, thank you for the really quick notice.

Comment: @DuckMan: `wx.App(False)` is the way to do it. Did you try after adding the paranthesis?

Comment: I've got that on line 9...  I'm even looking at the wxPython wiki and it does everything just the same.  I just attempted to replace the app.MainLoop() with wx.App(False) and again the program does nothing.

Comment: **FOUND IT**

I changed the id on line 10 from id=-1 to wx.ID_ANY

I guess the id=-1 is depreciated?

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: A `-1` is the same as `wx.ID_ANY`

Comment: @DuckMan it seems that the tutorial has a few problems, you might want to tell the author of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this problem, I changed the id tag on line 10 from

```
frame=duckie(parent=None, id=-1)
```

to

```
frame=duckie(None, wx.ID_ANY)
```